# How to check valid css text using zf2, and \Zend\Http\Client

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework2

My project theme , can override by `admin` users . There are few option for them to change css . When they define custom css , which they enter in `textarea`. it will overrider current layout theme. Most cases are change in background color, shadow .. This is shown in following image

[image: css text area]

How could I validate text entered in custom css textarea, is valid css text ? any suggestion please .

Comment: It depends on how "clever" it should be.

Comment: You should use the W3C service instead of regular expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330571/how-can-i-validate-css-within-a-script

Comment: Basically I'd validate separately text before block (selector) and each line inside block just for sanity `/^\s*[-a-z]+:[^;]+;/`

Comment: @antoox when I pass url http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?&profile=css3&output=text/plain&text=.navbar-inverse%20.nav%20%3E%20li%20%3E%20a%20%7B%20text-shadow:%200%200%201px%20#000000;%20%7D it shows error

Comment: It seems there is an error with the `.` character with the url service. However, you can also download the validator and run it locally: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html

Comment: @antoox I have added my code as a answer, you comments helps me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**w3.org** has API specifically for this:

**http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/api.html**

> What is this? Do I need it?
>
> The W3C CSS Validation Service is a free software created by the W3C
>   to help Web designers and Web developers check Cascading Style Sheets
>   (CSS). It can be used on this free service on the web, or downloaded
>   and used either as a java program, or as a java servlet on a Web
>   server.
>
> Do you need it? If you are a Web developer or a Web designer, this
>   tool will be an invaluable ally. Not only will it compare your style
>   sheets to the CSS specifications, helping you find errors, typos, or
>   incorrect uses of CSS, it will also tell you when your CSS poses some
>   risks in terms of usability.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected issue using following code .

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();

$request->setUri('http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator');
$request->setMethod('GET');
$request->getQuery()
        ->set('profile', 'css3')
        ->set('output', 'soap12')
        ->set('text', $_POST['custom_css'] );


$client     = new \Zend\Http\Client();
$response   = $client->dispatch(  $request );
$bodyXML    = $response->getBody() ;
```

And parsed response xml using `DOMDocument`

```
$domParser = new \DOMDocument( $bodyXML );
$domParser->loadXML( $bodyXML );

$errorCountNode = $domParser->getElementsByTagNameNs (
        'http://www.w3.org/2005/07/css-validator',
        'errorcount'
) ;

$errorCount = (int) $errorCountNode->item(0)->nodeValue;

if ( $errorCount >0 ){
    echo  'Custom css is not valid';
}
```

Hope this answer help somebody, who has same issue