# In PHP, is there a foolproof way to ensure a remote file is a CSS file?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using this code to get the mime type of remote files:

```
// check MIME Type
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer( file_get_contents( $source ) );
```

Then checking  if `$mime_type` contains the string 'text/css' to make sure the files are CSS.

However, I haven't found a site yet that uses the correct 'text/css' mime type for its CSS files. Most seem to be 'text/plain' or 'text/x-c++'.

Is there a better way to ensure remote files are CSS?

Comment: You can look at the extension and you can look at the mime-type but none of those are any guarantee. I don't know why some sites wouldn't give the proper mime-type, that seems lazy and wrong to me.

Comment: Well, a VERY safe way to do it would be to validate each file to get only real (valid) CSS files. You can use the validator suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3330582/3334049, although I have to say that this seems very overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is rendered client-side, so this seems like a pointless excercise. But I would agree that [finfo_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) is the way to go about this.